# Using COALESCE in Postgres and grouping by the resulting value

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I have two tables in a Postgres database:

table a

```
transaction_id | city   | store_name | amount
-------------------------------
123            | London | McDonalds  | 6.20
999            | NULL   | KFC        | 8.40
etc...
```

table b

```
transaction_id | location | store_name | amount
-----------------------------------
123            | NULL     | McDonalds  | 6.20
999            | Sydney   | KFC        | 7.60
etc...
```

As you can see, the location might be missing in one table but present in another table. For example with transaction 123, the location is present in table a but missing in table b. Apart from that, the rest of the data (`amount`, `store_name` etc.) is the same, row by row, assumed that we join on the `transaction_id`.

For a given merchant, I need to retrieve a list of locations and the total amount for that location.

An example of the desired result:

```
KFC sales Report:

suburb   | suburb_total
---------------
London   | 2500
Sydney   | 3500
```

What I tried:

```
select 
  coalesce(a.city, b.location) as suburb, 
  sum(a.amount) as suburbTotal
from tablea a
join tableb b on a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id
where a.store_name ilike 'KFC'
group by(suburb);
```

But I get the error `column "a.city" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

So I tried:

```
select 
  coalesce(a.city, b.location) as suburb, 
  sum(a.amount) as suburbTotal,
  max(a.city) as city_max,
  max(b.location) as location_max
from tablea a
join tableb b on a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id
where a.store_name ilike 'McDonalds'
group by(suburb);
```

But, surprisingly, I'm getting the same error, even thought I'm now using that column in an aggregate function.

How could I achieve the desired result?

NB there are reasons why we have de-normalised data across two tables, that are currently outside of my control. I have to deal with it.

EDIT: added FROM and JOIN, sorry I forgot to type those...

Comment: I did not understand your desired result ```London   | 2500```. Could you explain it? In your ```a``` and ```b``` tables there are different data for ```London```. Should it be ```12.4```?

Comment: Does it work if you repeat the expression: `group by coalesce(a.city, b.location)`  (btw: there is no need to enclose the group by columns with parentheses)

Comment: Your query is missing a `from` clause.

Comment: @Abdusoli imagine that in each table there are many more rows, and that's why I used a higher total in the desired result, I wanted to signify that this query makes sense where you have a larger number of rows...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it works! I don't know why, but it works!

Comment: @GMB thank you, edited question and sorry for accidental omission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only imagine getting that error with your query if `suburb` were a column in one of the tables.  One way around this is to define the value in the `from` clause:

```
select v.suburb, 
       sum(a.amount) as suburbTotal,
       max(a.city) as city_max,
       max(b.location) as location_max
from tablea a join
     tableb b
     on a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id cross join lateral
     (values (coalesce(a.city, b.location))) as v(suburb)
where a.store_name ilike 'McDonalds'
group by v.suburb;
```

This is one of the downsides of allowing column aliases in the `group by`.  Sometimes, you might have conflicts with table columns.

Comment: Indeed, suburb was the name of a column in one of the tables, I did not include this in my question because obviously I was trying to simplify the schema in a way that it's easy to follow. Your solution is very elegant - the other solution was proposed by @a_horse_with_no_name in the comments above, and it involves repeating the whole COALESCE expression in the group by clause - that works too! But I'm going to accept your answer as it is more elegant!

Answer (score 1):

Your querires are missing a `from` clause, which makes it unclear which logic you are trying to implement.

Based on your sample data and expected results, I think that's a `full join` on the `transaction_id`, and then aggregation. Using a positional parameter in the `group by` clause avoids repeating the expression:

```
select 
    store_name,
    coalesce(a.city, b.location) as suburb, 
    sum(amount) suburb_total
from tablea a
full join tableb b using(transaction_id)
group by 1, 2
```